# Remote database helper class

Tags: android, database, http

I have a remote data base that I want my app to communicate. I can already connect and use the database by using an http post and a php script to execute the sql. In the past I have made a helper class easily work with a local SQLiteDatabase. Can someone please point me in the direction of something similar for a remote database? I guess this would be more of a http post helper class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah that tutorial was not exactly what I had in mind but after looking at it I made a class that handles the http post and then parses the json for the specific php script that was run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **access remote database** it is better to use `json` parser.You can find tutorial [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)